# How to update a language's language code

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I have a multilingual site with English as default language.

The language code for English is currently `en` but I want to convert it to `en-US`.

I thought about adding a new language with the correct langcode, but I don’t think that’s the best solution since I have a lot of translated content, and I don’t want to add all the translations again for the new language.

Is it possible to update a current language's language code, if not, what can I then do?

**TL;DR**
I have a bunch of languages on my site, and I want to update all of their language codes without loosing my translations.

Comment: These files are only translation strings. A language exports/imports as `language.entity.[ID].yml`. You can add custom languages also in /admin/config/regional/language/add. But I'm not sure if you can convert a language.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But the problem is that I have to add all the translations again if I add a new language.

Comment: I don't know what is in the .pot file, but normally there is not much to translate from english to english. I think the bigger problem is how you can update the language code in entity tables.

Comment: Oh yeah, of course. Maybe I can create an update hook that copies the translations over.